# Global array losing its value

Tags: c, pointers, udp, ubuntu-16.04

I am working on a basic code which adds a layer of reliability over UDP protocol by adding a message id to each message and waiting for an acknowledgement for that message. I have used the following global buffers:

```
struct message {
    char *msg;
    struct sockaddr_in *srce_addr;
} *receive;    //store received messages
int rec_i = 0;

struct messageNtime {
    int id;
    char *msg;
    time_t tm;
    struct sockaddr_in *des_addr;
} *unacknowledged_message;   //store unacknowledged messages
int unack_i = 0;

int *received_message_id;   //store message ids
int msg_i = 0;
```

All the buffers were dynamically allocated space during the socket() call:

```
receive = (struct message *) calloc(100, sizeof(struct message));
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) receive[i].msg = (char *) calloc(100, sizeof(char));
unacknowledged_message = (struct messageNtime *) calloc(100, sizeof(struct messageNtime));
received_message_id = (int *) calloc(100, sizeof(int));
```

The main problem is with the receive[] buffer (so far).
There is a function 'HandleReceive' which looks like this:

```
void HandleReceive(int sockfd){
    char buf[100];
    struct sockaddr_in src_addr;
    socklen_t len=sizeof(src_addr);
    int n=recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buf, 100, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&src_addr, &len);
    if(n==4) HandleACKMsgRecv(buf);
    else HandleAppMsgRecv(sockfd,buf,n,&src_addr);
    for(int a=0; a < rec_i; a++) printf("HanReceive[%d]: %s\n",a,receive[a].msg);  //garbage
}
```

It calls the 'HandleAppMsgRecv' function which inserts a received message into the receive buffer:

```
void HandleAppMsgRecv(int sockfd, char *buf, int n, struct sockaddr_in *src_addr){
char app_msg[n-3],app_id[4];  //buf contains a id component and a message component.
for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) app_id[i]=buf[i];
for (i=0;i<n-4;i++) app_msg[i]=buf[i+4];
......
receive[rec_i].msg=app_msg;
receive[rec_i].srce_addr=src_addr;
rec_i++;
......
for(int a=0; a < rec_i; a++) printf("AppReceive[%d]: %s\n",a,receive[a].msg);  //Correct value
}
```

When I print the receive array at the end of (but inside) the HandleAppMsgRecv, I get the expected output (the buffer contains the received message). However, when I print the same array after the HandleAppMsgRecv() call in the HandleReceive function, I get some garbage value in the 1<sup>st</sup> index, and null values in the remaining indices. I insert the values one by one in the buffer, and this problem arises during every insertion.

Is there something I am missing here? Has anyone encountered this situation before and can shed some light? I am working on ubuntu 16.04.

I am also attaching the full code in case you want to run/check it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "rsocket.h"

//rsocket.c
struct message{
  char *msg;
  struct sockaddr_in *srce_addr;
 }*receive;
int rec_i=0;

struct messageNtime{
  int id;
  char *msg;
  time_t tm;
  struct sockaddr_in *des_addr;
}*unacknowledged_message;
int unack_i=0;

int *received_message_id;
int msg_i=0;

unsigned int message_id=1;

pthread_t tid;
pthread_mutex_t lock_rec=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,lock_unack=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,lock_id=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int search(int id){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<msg_i;i++) if(received_message_id[i]==id) return 1;
  return 0;
}

void searchNdelete(int m_id){
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<unack_i;i++)
    if(unacknowledged_message[i].id==m_id){
        for(j=i;j<unack_i-1;j++) unacknowledged_message[j]=unacknowledged_message[j+1];
        unack_i--;
        break;
    }
}

void HandleAppMsgRecv(int sockfd, char *buf, int n, struct sockaddr_in *src_addr){
  printf("In HandleAppMsgRecv\n");
  printf("n=%d\n", n);
  char app_msg[n-3],app_id[4];
  int i,ap_id;
  printf("a\n");
  for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) app_id[i]=buf[i];
  for (i=0;i<n-4;i++) app_msg[i]=buf[i+4];
  printf("b\n");
  app_msg[n-4]='\0';
  printf("c\n");
  ap_id=ntohl(*(int *)app_id);
  printf("Received MSG %d\n",ap_id );
  if(search(ap_id)==0){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_rec);
    received_message_id[msg_i]=ap_id;
    msg_i++;
    receive[rec_i].msg=app_msg;
    receive[rec_i].srce_addr=src_addr;
    rec_i++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_rec);
    for(i=0;i<rec_i;i++) printf("1.%s,%d ", receive[i].msg,strlen(receive[i].msg));
    printf("\n+++++++++++++++++++\n");
  }
  sendto(sockfd,app_id,4,0,(struct sockaddr *)src_addr, sizeof(*src_addr));
}

void HandleACKMsgRecv(char* buf){
  printf("In HandleACKMsgRecv\n");
  int ack_id=ntohl(*(int *)buf);
  printf("Received ACK %d\n",ack_id );
  searchNdelete(ack_id);
}

void HandleReceive(int sockfd){
  int n;
  char buf[100];
  struct sockaddr_in src_addr;
  socklen_t len;
  len=sizeof(src_addr);
  n=recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buf, 100, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&src_addr, &len);
  if(n==4) HandleACKMsgRecv(buf);
  else HandleAppMsgRecv(sockfd,buf,n,&src_addr);
  for(int i=0;i<rec_i;i++) printf("2.%s,%d ", receive[i].msg,strlen(receive[i].msg));
}

void HandleRetransmit(int sockfd){
  // printf("In HandleRetransmit\n");
  int i;
  time_t now;
  time(&now);
  for (i = 0; i < unack_i; i++){
    if(difftime(now,unacknowledged_message[i].tm)>=T){
        unacknowledged_message[i].tm=now;
        sendto(sockfd, unacknowledged_message[i].msg, strlen(unacknowledged_message[i].msg), 0, (const struct sockaddr *)unacknowledged_message[i].des_addr, sizeof(*unacknowledged_message[i].des_addr));
    }
    }
}

void *threadX(void *args){
  int *socket=(int *)args;
  int sockfd,r;
  sockfd=*socket;
  struct timeval *t;
  t=(struct timeval *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct timeval));
  t->tv_sec=T;
  t->tv_usec=0;
  fd_set readfs;
  while(1){
    FD_ZERO(&readfs);
    FD_SET(sockfd,&readfs);
    r=select(sockfd+1, &readfs, 0,0,t);
    if(r==0){
        t->tv_sec=T;
        t->tv_usec=0;
        HandleRetransmit(sockfd);   
    }
    else if(FD_ISSET(sockfd,&readfs))
        HandleReceive(sockfd);
  }
}


int r_socket(int domain, int type, int protocol){
  int sockfd,i;
  if(type!=SOCK_MRP) return -1;
  //Initializing tables
  receive=(struct message *)calloc(100,sizeof(struct message));
  for(i=0;i<100;i++) receive[i].msg=(char *)calloc(100,sizeof(char));
  unacknowledged_message=(struct messageNtime *)calloc(100,sizeof(struct messageNtime));
  received_message_id=(int *)calloc(100,sizeof(int));

  sockfd=socket(domain,SOCK_DGRAM,protocol);
  //create thread
  pthread_create(&tid,0,threadX,&sockfd);
  sleep(1);
  return sockfd;
}

int r_bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen){
  if(bind(sockfd,addr,addrlen)<0) return -1;
  else return 0;
}

int r_sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags, const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen){
  printf("In send\n");
  char msg[len+4];
  time_t curr_time;
  time(&curr_time);
  unsigned int id;
  int out;

  unacknowledged_message[unack_i].tm=curr_time;
  unacknowledged_message[unack_i].id=message_id;
  unacknowledged_message[unack_i].msg=(char *)buf;
  unacknowledged_message[unack_i].des_addr=(struct sockaddr_in *)dest_addr;
  unack_i++;

  id=htonl(message_id);
  memcpy(msg,&id,4);
  memcpy(&msg[4],buf,len);
  message_id++;

  out=sendto(sockfd, msg, len+4, flags, dest_addr, addrlen);
  printf("Out: %d\n", out);
  if(out>=0) return 0;
  return -1;
}

int r_recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen){
  printf("In recv\n");
   int i;
  // printf("rec_i: %d\n", rec_i);
  while(rec_i==0) sleep(0.1);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_rec);
  memcpy(buf,receive[0].msg,strlen(receive[0].msg));
  rec_i--;
  printf("---------------\n");
  for(i=0;i<rec_i;i++) receive[i]=receive[i+1];
  bzero(receive[rec_i].msg,100);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_rec);
  return strlen(buf);
}

int r_close(int sockfd){
  while(unack_i>0);
  pthread_cancel(tid);
  free(receive);
  free(received_message_id);
  free(unacknowledged_message);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock_id); 
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock_rec); 
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock_unack); 
  return close(sockfd);
}
```

With the header file rsocket.h, create a library (ar -rcs librsocket.a rsocket.o), then you can use the r_socket, r_bind, r_recvfrom, r_sendto, r_close functions in a basic udp server-client program to test.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

#ifndef rsocket   //rsocket.h
#define rsocket

#define SOCK_MRP 1
#define T 2 //Timeout
#define p 2 //Timeout

int r_socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
int r_bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
int r_sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags, const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);
int r_recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
int r_close(int sockfd);

#endif
```

Comment: Is there any chance ` char *buf ` is modified in ` // some code ` but you didn't see it ?

Comment: Please post [mcve]. From the posted code it is not even clear if you have alloated any memory for your "arrays".

Comment: How many elements of `struct message` do you allocate for the `receive` pointer? And what is supposed to happen when `rec_i` goes past the end of this allocation?

Comment: I have limited my input size to 100. But for now, I am checking with less than 10 inputs, when i have encountered this problem.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I am sorry, I thought it would be unnecessary to add that part because I got the expected values inside the function, which must mean there wasnt a problem with allocation. But I could be wrong and have added the calloc statements. I could post the entire code, but it is a bit lengthy.(200 lines)

Comment: @Martin, Yes, i did split that array to get the message part, which is still a character array. I have modified my question to include that part.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and clearly tell us where your print(buff) is successful and where it is unsucessful ?

Comment: @Martin, I have done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major error is in `HandleAppMsgRecv()`:

```
    receive[rec_i].msg=app_msg;
```

Although you had set up `receive[].msg` to point to an allocated memory area, you overwrite the pointer here with the address of the local array `app_msg` whose lifetime ends at exit from the function. Correct is of course e. g.:

```
    memcpy(receive[rec_i].msg, app_msg, sizeof app_msg);
```

A minor error is in `r_recvfrom()`:

```
  memcpy(buf,receive[0].msg,strlen(receive[0].msg));
  …
  return strlen(buf);
```

To correctly use `strlen(buf)`, `buf` is required to have a terminating null character at the end of the string, which isn't copied by the above `memcpy`. Correct is e. g.:

```
  memcpy(buf, receive[0].msg, strlen(receive[0].msg)+1);    // plus the '\0'!
  …
```